# Query Elasticsearch on AWS instance

Tags: api, elasticsearch, search

I'm pretty new to elasticsearch so having some trouble on how I can query the data using the ES API. For my local version of elasticsearch, I can enter something like this in my web browser to query:
`http://localhost:9200/company/_search?`
However, if I want to query the same thing on elasticsearch that is hosted on an ec2 instance, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Amazon Elasticsearch Service dashboard** page. This will have list of es. You will see your es on this page. Clicking on that will take you to details page. Under **Overview** tab, there will be something called endpoint. You can replace localhost with that value.

**http://{endpoint_value_from_overview_page}/company/_search?**

Comment: I have elasticsearch on an ec2 instance. I don't see it listed on the Amazon Elasticsearch Service dashboard

Comment: Then its http://{your_ec2_instance_address}:9200/company/_search?

Comment: Thank you so much!